# Android - switching back from UI thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have `MainActivity` and my separate class, name is `MyClass`. I want to run some code in `MyClass`. And I have methods for that in `MyClass`. In the constructor of `MyClass` I am passing `Context` of `MainActivity` class and converting that `Context` in `Activity`.

**MyClass.java**

```
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      this.activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    public void MyFunction() {
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          // Code
        }
    });
   }
```

Everything is going fine still here. In the `runOnUiThread`, I have written some code. There is a situation, After executing `runOnUiThread()` body, I want to go back to MyClass context. I want this to be done in `runOnUiThread()` only. Is there any way to switching back to  current thread again?

Thanks

Comment: _I want to again switch to current thread_ This means after running on UI Thread you want to get back to MyClass context ?

Comment: If not using `MyClass` class in separate Thread then no need to use `runOnUiThread` because  all code run on same thread

Comment: No. I want to use 'runOnUiThread'. Because I am using PubNub API. And that API requires 'runOnUiThread'. But in 'runOnUiThread' I want to again witch back to current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from question is that you need to run some code in UI thread and some in background thread. I yes, you may modify `MyClass` to use `Handler` as following.

```
private Context context;
private Handler backgroundHandler;
private Handler uiHandler;

public MyClass(Context context, Handler handler) {
  this.context = context;
  // this.activity = (Activity) context;
  this.uiHandler = handler;

  HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyClass.Handler");
  handlerThread.start();
  backgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
}

public void MyFunction() {
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          // Code to execute on ui thread

            backgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  // Code to execute on bg thread
                }
            });           
        }
    });
}
```

Pass the `Handler` as:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(context, new Handler());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the answers posted by ρяσѕρєя K or Kushal. Here are my 2 cents to make things a tad clear.

All the code inside `runOnUiThread` will be executed on UI thread and it can not be split into two parts; one running on UI thread and another in a different thread/context. Now, if you want to execute a code-block after `runOnUiThread` completes then you can modify your `runOnUiThread` function as below (as suggested in some of the answers here):

```
public void MyFunction() {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Add code to run on UI-Thread here
        }
    });
    // Add code to run on non UI-Thread here (i.e. on the calling Thread)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you access APIs for PubNub from `runOnUiThread()`, android system will switch the processing to your current thread automatically and executes outer statements :

```
    public void MyFunction() {
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          // Code which runs on MAIN UI thread
        }
    });
    // once upper part is done, switching to current thread
    // these statements will be execute on current thread
    // statement 1;
    // ...
   }
```

Comment: I want to switch back to current thread in the runOnUiThread block only

Comment: Why you want to do that explicitely. If you execute all code from `runOnUiThread()` part and do nothing, then android system will automatically execute later part in your current thread. So, whatever you want to call from `runOnUiThread()` part, that calls can be made from outside as explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you define and implement a custom class in the activity class, unless you create a new thread, all of your code will run in the UI thread.

The `runOnUiThread` method passes the information necessary to have a different thread reference the UI thread for updating views or other UI components.

To run code in your original class you should do a few things. First, you should define it as a separate class (in another file, not as a private class).

Second, you should pass it the `Activity` (maybe as a `WeakReference`) and then use the `Activity` method "runOnUiThread" when necessary.

Another option is to create a `Handler` or `Thread` to run off the UI when you want it to run.

You are not entirely clear about your use-case...